# asp.net mvc send httpstatuscode 200 but not return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I'm working on an asp.net mvc web app and am implementing paypal. I have everything working correctly with the IPN but paypal has a time limit of 30 seconds that it will wait for a response. I'm currently updating the customer database before `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK)` Like I said, this works fine, however I was hoping to be able to send the status code so that I'm finished working with the ipn and paypal can finish listening then I will update the customer database in case something goes wrong in the update process and it takes longer than the 30 seconds. How can I send the HttpStatusCode but not return from the function? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried spawning a new thread that handles the processing of the data?

Comment: I haven't, I unfortunately am not that strong in async coding (head hung in shame) so I haven't gone that route yet.

Comment: If you share the code snippet of the method (with the grunt work of the processing removed), then we can help show you how that can be accomplished.  Or even better, [read up on it a bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and give it a try.  If it's still not working, post your code here and we can help fill the gaps in your understanding. :)

Comment: Great, thank you. I will read up on it and see what I can come up with on my own first.

Comment: IMHO, kinda defeats one of the purposes of IPN re: - if you don't "care" to let Paypal know if you've processed the notification _successfully_ ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. 200 is a *response* status code. By sending 200, you are sending the response. The request-response cycle is then complete. If you need to take care of some long-running task, then you need to off-load it to a separate process. Look at something like [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com/).